# Get Object type from PropertyType?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have Type of a property.  `propertyType` is basically a

```
public abstract Type PropertyType { get; }
```

From this I want to know Object type which is `Employee`:

```
propertyType    {Name = "Employee[]"  FullName = "DataContract.Employee[]"}
```

How can I get this?

Comment: What do you mean by this "From this I want to know Object type which is Employee." ?

Comment: [This?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: My property is of type public Employee[] {get; set;}. But I have property type value from which I want to know this property is of type Employee.

Answer (score 1):

```
Type t;
if (propertyType.IsArray) // true
   t = propertyType.GetElementType(); // t = Employee
```